# React Native TextInput on iOS hides keyboard after one keystroke

Tags: ios, react-native, keyboard, textinput

import React from 'react';
import {
    TextInput,
    KeyboardAvoidingView,
    StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';

import Colors from '../constants/Colors';

const QaTextInput = ({ style, minWidth, maxWidth, placeholder }) => {
    const input = {
        height: 35,
        minWidth: minWidth,
        maxWidth: maxWidth,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: Colors.input,
        backgroundColor: Colors.input
    };

```
return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
        behavior="position"
        keyboardVerticalOffset="100"
        enabled>
        <TextInput
            placeholder={placeholder}
            autoFocus={true}
            showSoftInputOnFocus={true}
            style={input}
        />
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
);
```

};

export default QaTextInput;

Answer (score 1):

It was how I was using the component. One of the parents was a Text node. Changing that to a View solved it.